# Change reference point when rotating image in IE using MatrixFilter

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, matrix, rotation

I've found that you can rotate an image in IE using the MatrixFilter, examples can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28VS.85%29.aspx) but the rotation point seems to move about as you increase the angle.